# Print a list only if values existing in Map in Mustache Java

Tags: java, mustache

I wish to print an a List only if items exist. I can do the following which will print out the list items if they exist.

```
<ul>
{{#myList}}
<li>{{value}}</li>
{{/myList}}
</ul>
```

However, if the list is empty, I don't want to print out the `<ul></ul>` tags either. I can achieve this by adding another property to my context `context.isEmpty = myList.isEmpty();` but I want to avoid this - the list itself already has an `isEmpty()` on it, is there some way I can reference this?

Is this posible is Mustache Java?

Answer (score 1):

I had to follow what is described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mustachejava/UmVGdNtjlpM

```
DefaultMustacheFactory factory = new DefaultMustacheFactory(); 
factory.setObjectHandler(new ReflectionObjectHandler() { 
  @Override 
  protected boolean areMethodsAccessible(Map<?, ?> map) { 
    return true; 
  } 
}); 

{{#job.userMetadata.entrySet}} 
  <tr> 
    <td>{{key}}</td> 
    <td>{{value}}</td> 
  </tr> 
{{/job.userMetadata.entrySet}}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a `myList.size` before your `<ul></ul>`?

```
{{#myList.size}}
    <ul>
        {{#myList}}
            <li>{{value}}</li>
        {{/myList}}
        </ul>
{{/myList.size}}
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. (Neither does using isEmpty)

Comment: Have you tried instead of `isEmpty` using just `empty` ?

Comment: Yes I tried both, it didn't work. See my answer for what I had to do.